# Activation function for multilayer perceptron

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, perceptron

I have tried to train simple backpropagation neural network with the `xor` function. When I use `tanh(x)` as activation function, with the derivative `1-tanh(x)^2`, I get the right result after about 1000 iterations. However, when I use `g(x) = 1/(1+e^(-x))` as an activation function, with the derivative `g(x)*(1-g(x))`, I need about 50000 iterations to get the right result. What can be the reason?

Thank you.

Comment: A too small learning rate maybe?:p How have you encoded your XOR dataset? `1 0 = 1` or `-1 1 = 1`?

Comment: But why should the learning constant be fine for tanh, but not good enough for the logistic function? I considered "1" output as true, "0" as false.

Comment: What do you mean by "the result"? How good is the prediction after 500 episodes for both activation functions?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, what you observe is true. I have similar observations when training neural networks using back propagations. For `XOR` problem, I used to set up a `2x20x2` network, logistic function takes 3000+ episodes to get below result:

```
[0, 0] -> [0.049170633762142486]
[0, 1] -> [0.947292007836417]
[1, 0] -> [0.9451808598939389]
[1, 1] -> [0.060643862846171494]
```

While using `tanh` as activation function, here is the result after 800 episodes. `tanh` converges consistently faster than `logistic`.

```
[0, 0] -> [-0.0862215901296476]
[0, 1] -> [0.9777578145233919]
[1, 0] -> [0.9777632805205176]
[1, 1] -> [0.12637838259658932]
```

The two functions' shape look like below (credit: [efficient backprop](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi08/cse253/Handouts/lecun-98b.pdf)):

[image: activation funcs]

- The left is the standard logistic function: `1/(1+e^(-x))`.
- The right is the `tanh` function, also known as hyperbolic tangent.

It's easy to see that `tanh` is antisymmetric about the origin.

According to  [efficient Backprop](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi08/cse253/Handouts/lecun-98b.pdf),

> **Symmetric sigmoids** such as `tanh` often converge faster than standard logistic function.

Also from wiki [Logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function):

> Practitioners caution that sigmoidal functions which are **antisymmetric about the origin** (e.g. the **hyperbolic tangent**) lead to **faster** convergence when training networks with backpropagation.

See [efficient Backprop](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi08/cse253/Handouts/lecun-98b.pdf) for more details explaining the intuition here.

See [elliott](http://www.heatonresearch.com/wiki/Elliott_Activation_Function) for an alternative of `tanh` with easier computations. It's shown below as the black curve (the blue one is the original `tanh`).

[image]

[image]

> Two things should stand out from the above chart. First, TANH usually needed fewer iterations to train than Elliott. So the training accuracy is not as good with Elliott, for an Encoder. However, notice the training times. Elliott completed its entire task, even with the extra iterations it had to do, in half the time of TANH. This is a huge improvement and literally means that in this case, Elliott will cut your training time in half, and deliver the same final training error. While it does take more training iterations to get there, the speed per iteration is so much faster it still results in the training time being cut in half.